# How do I ceate an image without background from scratch?

Tags: image, blender

I have this image I am trying to use in blender:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfweW.png)

When I try to remove background using online tools, the background turns full black. How do I remove the background or how do I make the same image from scratch without background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using Gimp, a free image editing tool, which you can download [on gimp.org](https://www.gimp.org)

[Here is a visual guide to the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWkaI.jpg)

Install it, and open the image in Gimp. On the right hand side you'll see the layer controls - and there will be a layer with your image on it. Right-click on it, and select "Add alpha channel". If this option is greyed out then you already have one, and you can just move to the next step.

In the toolshelf you will find a tool that looks like a magic wand - click it. It will select all connected pixels of one color of your choosing - so go ahead and left-click the white area. Everything white will be selected. Hit the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to remove it. Now you should see a checkerboard pattern as the background.

You might need to remove the white areas in the zeros and O-s as well.

Once done, go to `File -> Export` and export it as a `.png` image.

If you purely want to stick to blender: Feed the image into the Color of a diffuse shader, and use it as a mask to mix the diffuse with a transparent shader.

Answer (score -1):

Most image formats store the colour of each pixel for an image. When you delete part of the image, the image editor replaces that area with another colour, this will either be the background colour set in the program or it will set the [transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(graphic)) which is stored in the alpha channel of formats that support it. Not all image editors support alpha transparency, when they do, you may need to specifically edit or add the alpha channel to get a transparent background for your image.

Blender can render images with a transparent background, you can find the relevant settings [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/935).